# rspec: can't define singleton Error when trying to mock 1.month-ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I'm trying to test the following method:

```
  def update_players_data(team_id, import_id)
    team = Team.find(team_id)
    players_to_update = team.players.where("updated_at < ?", 1.month.ago)
    players_to_update.each { |player| update_player(player, import_id) }
  end
```

With this test class:

```
  context "update_players_data" do
    let(:player1) { double(:player) }
    let(:player2) { double(:player) }
    let(:players) { [player1, player2]}
    let(:players_to_update) { [player1] }
    let(:date) { 1.month.ago }
    let(:import_id) { "import_id" }
    let(:team_id) { "team_id" }
    let(:team) { double(:team) }

    before do
      allow(Team).to receive(:find).with(team_id) { team }
      allow(team).to receive(:players) { players }
      allow(1).to receive_message_chain(:month, :ago) { date }
      allow(players).to receive(:where).with("geocoded_at < ?", date) { players_to_update }
    end

    it "calls update_player" do
      subject.update_players_data(team_id, import_id)
      expect(subject).to have_received(:update_player).with(player1, import_id)
    end
  end
```

But the tests breaks when it tries to mock the date here:

```
allow(1).to receive_message_chain(:month, :ago) { date }
```

throwing 'TypeError: can't define singleton '

The problem is I cannot just call 1.month.ago inside the test because test date differs with the date on execution time by miliseconds causing the test to fail. Date has to be mocked. But I cannot find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop).

Additionally

```
    players_to_update = team.players.where("updated_at < ?", 1.month.ago)
    players_to_update.each { |player| update_player(player, import_id) }
```

can be

```
    team.players.where("updated_at < ?", 1.month.ago).update_all(import_id: import_id)
```

(assuming you're just updating the value inside that function).

Comment: Alternatively, if you're rails5+, you could use the build in time travel helpers. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html

Comment: @DanielWestendorf I hate to admit I didn't know about this!  Better answer, IMO.